# How to merge multiple dynamic queries

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql

I'm using `node` to communicate with my `postgresql` database.
I have a list of cars:

```
[{id:1, areaId: 1}, 
 {id:2, areaId: 2}, 
 {id:3, areaId: 2}]
```

`areaId` is a column in another table (say `areas`), and I want to fetch the area name for each car:

```
select name from areas
where id = areaId
```

How can I build a list containing all the cars with the area name attached?
The naive approach is to `query` the database for each object:

```
const query = `select name from areas
                 where id = $1`;
return pg.query(query, car.areaId);
```

But it seems like a lot of queries to be executed.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking: do you have a table of "cars" with names, and a table of "areas" with names, and you want your results to have maybe: `car.id`, `car.name`, `area.name`?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to select multiples Id's at the same time as this.

```
SELECT name
FROM areas
where ID in (5263, 5625, 5628, 5621)
```

Comment: does it return the values in the same order they were requested?

Comment: I'm not completely sure if the default follows the order, but you should be able to request also the Id in the select and then order them by ID.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can specify multiple `car.id`s and fetch `car.name` and `area.name` and return them together.

Further you can sort the response by `car.id` using `ORDER BY`.  I am not aware of any way to enforce the ordering based on the order of the passed in IDS, but you could easily sort the results in memory very quickly with JavaScript.

There are multiple ways to do this in SQL: inner join, full join, subselect...maybe more.  I'll demonstrate the "inner join" as it's usually the most efficient, and some SQL query planners will convert subselects to inner joins anyway.

You haven't specified, but assuming you're using `node-postgres`...here's an answer when `carIds` is already defined, as an array:

**Inner join**

```
const query = `SELECT car.id, car.name, areas.name FROM car INNER JOIN area ON car.areaId WHERE car.id = ANY (${carIds}) ORDER BY car.id`
```

Finally:

```
return pq.query(query, carIds)
```